# Slow performance on LINQ query against SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4, geonames

I want to find geographic names that starts with characters entered in a search box. Some geographic names have alternative names in other languages. These alternative names are stored in a separate table.

```
GN_Name 1 - 0:N GN_AlternateName
```

(PK)GN_Name.GeoNameId == (FK)GN_AlternateName.GeoNameId

I want to search the name in GN_AlternateName.AlternateName first and if that doesn't exist, use the corresponding GN_Name.Name.

I wrote following LINQ query:

```
return (from name in db.GN_Name
        where name.CountryCode == "se"
        join alt in db.GN_AlternateName 
        on name.GeoNameId equals alt.GeoNameId into outer
        from alt in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where ((alt.IsoLanguage == "sv" && 
                alt.AlternateName.StartsWith(query)) || 
                name.Name.StartsWith(query))
        select new GeoNameModel { 
            Language = alt.IsoLanguage, 
            Name = (alt == null ? name.Name : alt.AlternateName),
            FeatureClass = name.FeatureClass, 
            FeatureCode = name.FeatureCode, 
            GeoNameId = name.GeoNameId, 
            UniqueName = name.UniqueName,
            UniqueCount = name.UniqueCount}).Take(HB.AutoCompleteCount);
```

That translates into the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[GeoNameId] AS [GeoNameId], 
[Limit1].[IsoLanguage] AS [IsoLanguage], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[FeatureClass] AS [FeatureClass], 
[Limit1].[FeatureCode] AS [FeatureCode], 
[Limit1].[UniqueName] AS [UniqueName], 
[Limit1].[UniqueCount] AS [UniqueCount]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (5) 
    [Extent1].[GeoNameId] AS [GeoNameId], 
    [Extent1].[FeatureClass] AS [FeatureClass], 
    [Extent1].[FeatureCode] AS [FeatureCode], 
    [Extent1].[UniqueName] AS [UniqueName], 
    [Extent1].[UniqueCount] AS [UniqueCount], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[AlternateNameId] IS NULL) THEN [Extent1].[Name] ELSE [Extent2].[AlternateName] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[IsoLanguage] AS [IsoLanguage]
    FROM  [dbo].[GN_Name] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GN_AlternateName] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GeoNameId] = [Extent2].[GeoNameId]
    WHERE (''se'' = [Extent1].[CountryCode]) AND (((''sv'' = [Extent2].[IsoLanguage]) AND ([Extent2].[AlternateName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'')) OR ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~''))
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'ja%',@p__linq__1=N'ja%'
```

I can't really see whats wrong with it, but it takes around 5 seconds to complete.

Should i add some index? Maybe set up an indexed view? 
My SQL server knowledge is limited and i would love to get back to some real coding ;)

Any suggestions warmly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I'm using SQL server 2008. Following the instructions of taylonr i got the following results.
[image: Client statistics]
[image: Execution plan]
[image: Execution plan details]

There are 3 "parts" that make up 100% of the total. I, however, don't have a clue on how to use these statistics.

**UPDATE 2**

SSMS Execution Plan recommended the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_GN_Name_CountryCode
ON [dbo].[GN_Name] ([CountryCode])
INCLUDE ([GeoNameId],[Name],[FeatureClass],[FeatureCode],[UniqueName],[UniqueCount])
```

I added it and the query now runs much better!

**UPDATE 3**
taylonr suggests using only one LIKE clause. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Anyone up for the challenge?

Comment: you need to add an execution plan at least ... if you want help diagnosing what is wrong

Comment: I've added the execution plan now.

Comment: you are going to need an index on countrycode, possibly a covering one

Comment: Take a look at UPDATE 2...is the index i added what you meant?

Comment: When I said having "2 separate like statements isn't helping much" what I really meant was that like statements are slower.  I'm not sure you can reduce the number of like statements.  It was more of a general observation for future consideration, use as few likes as is possible

Comment: In your case, the two "starts with" method calls are converted into SQL `LIKE` operations.  From a SQL Standpoint, you could use the `LEFT` function to truncate the column values and then perform an equals comparison between the input and truncated column values.  Unfortunately, I don't know which (if any) built-in string method call will force LINQ to SQL to invoke the SQL `LEFT` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd be careful about calling SQL not "real coding" since it looks like improvement there could help you out ;) (I'm a C# guy, and not a SQL expert, just sayin...)

Go in to your SSMS, and take the query that is generated.

Copy that into a new Query Window.

Now do 2 things before your run it.
1. Go into the Query menu and click "Include Client Statistics"
2. Go into the Query menu and click "Include Actual Execution plan"

Now run your query.

When the query is done, check the Client statistics for the item labeled "Wait time on server replies"  this is the amount of time (in ms) that the server is executing for this query.

The "Total Execution time" is the amount of time it took the client & server to communicate the data.

That will give you an idea of what the time is like on the server.  For example, if that's 10ms and it takes 5s to execute from your code, Sql might not be the problem.

Next, open your execution plan tab.  This will show you how SQL generated this data.  For example, if it spent 100% of the time doing a table scan (as opposed to an index scan) then you might want to add some indexes.

Take a look at the execution plan and see what has the highest percentage.  This will give you an idea of where you might be able to optimize your query.

I would guess that having the two separate 'like' statements probably isn't helping much.  Like statements aren't as performant as an equality, e.g.

```
WHERE name = 'taylonr'
```

is quicker than

```
WHERE name like 'taylo%'
```

Comment: Of course i consider SQL real coding but it's not really my cup of tea, hence i added the winking smiley to display that i'm aware of my bias. 

I will have a look at your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I have been oblivious to these really handy features of SSMS. I will add the results to the question.

Comment: It would be great having just one LIKE clause. Any ideas on how to write a query having only one?

Comment: I knew you were mostly joking about the SQL... I didn't neccessarily mean only have 1 like clause, but rather if at all possible reduce the amount of 'like' statements you do.

Comment: I see. Your response helped me improve the performance a lot. You get the answer and thumbs up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could run the query in [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx).

It will make index suggestions after analyzing the query.

Comment: I would like to here what it says about ""where ((alt.IsoLanguage=="sv" && alt.AlternateName.StartsWith(query)) || name.Name.StartsWith(query))""

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am now running the tuning advisor with the above query as workload. Just have to roll my thumbs for an hour.

Comment: Tuning Advisor gave no partition or index recommendations. Under execution plan in SSMS i found a recommendation. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try breaking this into 3 or so separate requests?  Then see if any one of them is abnormally long.  Putting all your work into one single return() makes it really hard to diagnose things.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion if Tuning Advisor won't provide any magic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that EF is turning your parameters @p_*linq*_1 nvarchar(4000) into nvarchar and my guess is that in the database they are stored as  varchar forcing sql server to cast them.

I ran into the same problem.  Try running the sql in query analyzer and change the types of the parameters to varchar and see if it runs faster.

Comment: Why the downvote? I can guarantee that this happens. I've seen it in EF and Nhibernate. I don't know that this is the case here or not without knowing the data type of the column but it certainly worth checking.

Comment: Wasn't me ;) Both name fields are nvarchar so changing the query to varchar actually made it worse. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could help is if the translated from clause looked like this

```
FROM [dbo].[GN_Name] AS [Extent1] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GN_AlternateName] AS [Extent2] 
ON [Extent1].[GeoNameId] = [Extent2].[GeoNameId]) AS [Limit1] 
AND ( 'sv' = [Extent2].[IsoLanguage] )
```

I'm guess that would mean the linq would be here.

```
join alt in db.GN_AlternateName 
on name.GeoNameId equals alt.GeoNameId && alt.IsoLanguage == 'sv'
```

Also I would *consider* indexes on the following fields. But the Tuning Advisor should really tell you one way or another.

```
GN_Name.GeoNameId
GN_AlternateName.GeoNameId
GN_Name.CountryCode
GN_Name.Name
GN_AlternateName.AlternateName
```